# Nicer output for output of function applied to every column

Tags: r, apply, dplyr

I am trying to find out some summary statistics about a data.frame:

```
avg.nas <- apply(my.data, 2, function(x) mean(is.na(x)))
```

This gives the expected result: a named numeric vector with a value for each column. The problem is that this value is awkward to pipe into other operations (such as joining it to a description of each variable). I know I can fiddle with some combination of `sapply`, `rownames`, `t`, `as.data.frame`, and mutations to get what I want, but is there a more idiomatic way to get this sort of summary statistic from the data frame?

To be clear, what I want is

```
avg.nas <- as.data.frame(avg.nas)
names(avg.nas) <- "prop.missing"
avg.nas$Variable <- rownames(avg.na)
```

Comment: Average number of `NA`s in each column. Using `lapply` or `sapply` still requires a few operations to return the vector to a natural data.frame.

Comment: The function is fine. It's the structure of the output that is problematic.

Comment: If you are okay with `factor` column, `stack` would be option.  `setNames(stack(colMeans(is.na(my.data))),c('prop.missing', 'Variable'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not entirely clear on what you're looking for, but maybe this is another option:

```
library(reshape2)
x <- data.frame(x = 1:5,y = 6:10)
x[c(1,3),1] <- NA
> setNames(melt(lapply(x,function(x) mean(is.na(x)))),c('Mean','Variable'))
  Mean Variable
1  0.4        x
2  0.0        y
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rowMeans` on the `NA` values without `apply`. From your question, it seems like you may want to add a new column with the proportions of NA per row.

```
> m <- data.frame(matrix(c(1,NA,5,NA,NA,7,8,NA), 2))
> m$prop.missing <- rowMeans(is.na(m))
> m
  X1 X2 X3 X4 prop.missing
1  1  5 NA  8         0.25
2 NA NA  7 NA         0.75
> is.data.frame(m)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: `rowMeans` is a lot more efficient, thank you, but the efficiency of the `apply` function wasn't the problem.. My inteded output from this would be `data.frame(Vars = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), prop.missing = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5))`

Comment: I've added a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Never use `apply` on a `data.frame`. This will coerce it to a matrix which and will not be memory efficient (let alone the changes to a consistent type)

`lapply` will cycle through the columns and return a list.

```
  as.data.frame(lapply(m, function(x) mean(is.na(x))))
```

Comment: Not sure if that code will do it.`lapply` runs on a list.  The columns of a matrix are vectors.

Comment: @RichardScriven The OP specifically stated that their object is a data frame, which is why mnel included the comment about using apply.